# Usb drive not detected /arch

Tags: usb-drive

I have this USB drive that doesn't seem to be detected neither on lsblk or fdisk.
Here are some outputs:

Dmesg:

```
[93812.546850] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 33 using ehci-pci
[93812.631628] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[93812.632314] scsi host18: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
```

udevadm:

```
UDEV  [93905.859931] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [93905.878766] change   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/host20/target20:0:0/20:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
```

fdisk:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No medium found
```

mount:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb
mount: special device /dev/sdb1 does not exist
```

journalctl:

```
mtp-probe[28286]: bus: 2, device: 39 was not an MTP device
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be and how should I fix it?

Comment: Why do you say it's not recognized? It seems to have been attached as `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: Thought so myself but then when I try to mount it I get "no medium found on /dev/sdb"

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and include the mount command you tried and the error message. Also show us the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`. Are there any partitions on the drive?

Comment: Done. Yeah there is a partition on the drive, last I checked on a windows pc I was able to open it.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please also show the `mount` command and its error so we have everything included in the question. Oh, please don't add "edit" when you edit, questions should stand alone, there's no need to highlight edits here.

Comment: can you inspect systems log for error related to ehci_pci? Or a line like "mtp-probe: bus: X, device:Y was not an MTP device"

Comment: @LilloX yep, editing post ..

Comment: ok, take a look here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=119676 maybe can solve your problem

Comment: Already visited the post, didn't help. I should add I did a lot a lot of searching before I decided to post here, couldn't find a solution elsewhere. But might as well have missed the "golden" post that fixes my issue so yeah.

Comment: Removing libmtp rida of the last "error" but nothing  much changes after that. Blkid doesnt detect it either

Comment: When I plug a USB device into my system, I see the device in `dmesg`, as in your case, `sdb`. For devices that fail with `No medium found` I generally have the error there, too. Are you sure that is all that `dmesg`  reports when you insert the drive, could you wait a minute before running `dmesg`  ?

Answer (score 2):

"No medium found" makes me think the drive might be failing its internal diagnostics and presenting itself as a "drive with no disk inserted" as a way to indicate a fault.

Try running:

```
sudo smartctl -x /dev/sdb
```

SMART diagnostics don't always work with USB drives, but it's worth a try.

You might also try unplugging & replugging the USB drive several times: if the drive health is borderline, you might get lucky and the drive might successfully start up eventually. If that happens, the first thing to do is to backup anything valuable that you might have on that drive.